# the add_subplot in matplotlib, Why I couldn't find projection type '3d' in documents?

Tags: python, matplotlib

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html?highlight=hist3d

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4, range=[[0, 4], [0, 4]])

# Construct arrays for the anchor positions of the 16 bars.
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1] + 0.25, yedges[:-1] + 0.25, indexing="ij")
xpos = xpos.ravel()
ypos = ypos.ravel()
zpos = 0

# Construct arrays with the dimensions for the 16 bars.
dx = dy = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dz = hist.ravel()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, zsort='average')

plt.show()
```

in add_subplot:
projection{None, 'aitoff', 'hammer', 'lambert', 'mollweide', 'polar', 'rectilinear', str}, optional

Why I couldn't find projection type '3d' in documents of 'projection'?

Comment: matplotlib builds its docs using matplotlib, so the code at https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html?highlight=hist3d must work.  If it doesn't for you, then you have an installation problem, or have a Matplotlib that is too old.

Comment: The code works for me well, but I just couldn't find the '3d' option in the docs of "projection", how on earth does this '3d' work, and is there anyother way of impliment 3d subplot except "projection = '3d' " acordding to the current docs(I mean I could find in docs)?